# Forward Zend_Mail_Message

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, forwarding

Is there an easy way how I could forward `Zend_Mail_Message` to another recipient?

I would like just add the recipients address, "FWD:" to subject and forward existing `Zend_Mail_Message` as attachment or inline message.

Comment: @akond: easy would be what mailo said - just old existing mail into `Zend_Mail` and `send()` it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant something like

```
$oldMail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap();
$mail = new Zend_Mail($oldMail);
$mail->addTo($oneEmail);
$mail->send();
```

Then no, it's not possible. But you can always manually change the subject, add recipient's, and create an attachment from your old message:

```
//connect with imap
$oldMail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array(
                                     'host'     => 'example.com',
                                     'user'     => 'test',
                                     'password' => 'test'));
$newBody = $_POST['body']; //new body text
//If you want to download previous message
$messageNum = 8; //you have to know message number
$oldMessage = $mail->getMessage($messageNum); //in order to get it

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo($oldMail->getEmail())
     ->setSubject('RE: ' . $message->subject)
     ->setBodyText($newBody);

//create an attachment
$attachment = $mail->createAttachment($message->getContent());
$attachment->type = 'text/plain';
$attachment->filename = 'RE.txt';
$message->addAttachment($attachment);

$mail->addTo($email);
$mail->send();
```

Additionally this may be [helpful](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html)