# How to forward mail message using Zend Mail?

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, zend-mail

How do I forward Zend Mail Message using Zend Mail?

I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117539/forward-zend-mail-message) with one answer, but this solution does not work (the body content is encoded)

Comment: That doesn't mean the given answer does not help. Just deal with the body content differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward Zend_Mail_Message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117539/forward-zend-mail-message)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decode the body of the email message.

```
$content = $part->getContent();
        try {
            switch ($part->contentTransferEncoding) {
                case 'base64':
                    $content = base64_decode($content);
                    break;
                case 'quoted-printable':
                    $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
                    break;
            }
        } catch(Zend_Mail_Exception $e) { } //content encoding header not set
```